# Not able to change the title with metadata when using 'use client' in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a `/demo` route in my Next.js `13` application, and it is using the `App Router`. But I am unable to change the title of the page (the current title I am getting is localhost:3000/demo).

I have the following code.

`/demo/page.js`:

```
'use client'

 ....

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Demo - ModalJS',
};

export default Demo(){
 return ...
}
```

The `'use client'` is creating the problem, because when I remove it Title changes, but the problem is that I cannot remove it because this component uses `onClick` which gives an error without ''use client`'

The code inside `Demo` is as follows:

```
export default function Demo() {
    

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("Title of your modal");
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState("You description goes here");
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

    const handleclick = ()=>{
        const modal = new ModalJS( ... stuff related to this library)
        
        modal.show()       //trigger this when you want to show modal
    }


    return <section id={styles.demosection}>
        <div className={styles.demotitle}>Demo</div>
        <div className={styles.form}>
            <label htmlFor="title" className={styles.label}>Title:</label> <br />
            <input type="text" name="title" id={styles.title} className={styles.input} value={title} onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
<br /><br />
            <label htmlFor="desc" className={styles.label}>Description:</label> <br />
            <input type="text" name="desc" id={styles.desc} className={styles.input} value={desc} onChange={(e)=>setDesc(e.target.value)}/>
<br /><br />
            <label htmlFor="theme" className={styles.label}>Theme:</label> <br />
            <select type="select" name="theme" id={styles.theme} className={styles.input} onChange={(e)=>setTheme(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="light">light</option>
                <option value="dark">dark</option>
            </select>
<br /><br />

        </div>
        <div className={styles.showbtndiv}>
            <button className={styles.showbtn} onClick={()=>handleclick()}>Show Modal</button>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata), you cannot have `metadata` in a client component. Here is the quote where they warn about that:

> Both static and dynamic `metadata` through `generateMetadata` **are only supported in Server Components**.

So instead of having the whole page (or layout) as a client component, you could move the part where you need interactivity in a client file and import it into your server page, as they [say](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#moving-client-components-to-the-leaves):

> To improve the performance of your application, we recommend moving Client Components to the leaves of your component tree where possible.

In your case, you could move the content of your current `app/demo/page.js` file inside a `app/demo/demo.js` file, for example, without the `metadata`, and import it:

```
// app/demo/page.js

import Demo from "./demo";

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Demo - ModalJS',
};

export default Page(){
 return <div><Demo/></div>
}
```

```
// app/demo/demo.js

'use client'

// ....

export default Demo(){
 return ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

As every **page.js** can have a **layout.js**, you can leverage that to add the metadata onto the **layout.js** of that **page.js**.

In your case, it would look like this

`/app/demo/page.js` - stays the same

`/app/demo/layout.js` :

```js
import { Metadata } from "next";
import Page from "./page";   // import your Demo's page

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Your Title',
  description:
    "Your Description",
};
export default Page;
```

**Automatically your metadata shall be added.**