# How to set <head> tags for client-side ('use client') component in nextjs if Manifest method used everywhere else?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Basically the `<Head>` tag from `next/head` is not working:

I have used the `Manifest` type to set header tags for the other pages and it works ok. But because of a need for `useState()` on one of my pages, I had to declare `'use client'` at the top of that page, which makes it incompatible with the `Manifest` method of setting  tags.

So I `import Head from 'next/head'` and directly set a  and meta description. It doesn't work. Instead, it uses the defaults / fallbacks from my main layout. According to [this old comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42708#issuecomment-1309627297), I can use a `head.js` workaround but the pages it links to suggest this method is obsolete.

So how to set head tag values for a client side page in this scenario?

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445050/not-able-to-change-the-title-with-metadata-when-using-use-client-in-next-js) might give you a hint.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar omg thank you! That was it! I thought the entire chain, from the file for the page.tsx all the way down to leaf components had to be marked 'use client'. Apparently I can restrict 'use client' to just those leaf nodes where it's needed and I can  just leave my page as-is!

Comment: Glad I could give the hint ! Voting as duplicate to help others find the thread. Have a good one !